is there any way of using a data url for an image with slack incoming webhook?
I'm using an incoming webhook to send messages to slack.  I want colored text and formatted tables in my messages - which slack seems to have made an effort to prevent - so the only way it seems I can do it is to attach an image - ie I'll write text and tables into an image and then attach it as an image.
however - I don't have an always available to everyone and easy to write to store for those images - I really want to put the image into the message.   Is it possible to do that in some way?   I tried converting the image to a data url - and it didn't seem to work, but I'm wondering if I did something wrong.
here's an example of a message I tried
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "image",
            "title": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "anything",
                "emoji": true
            },
            "image_url": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
            "alt_text": "an image"
        }
    ]
}

Fundamentally - the problem I have is that I don't have anywhere publicly available that I can just drop an image and turn it into a url that slack can read.
